# Need help centering navigation bar

Tags: html, css, header, nav

First off I'm trying to make a navigation bar that's horizontal and stays fixed at the top.

I'm trying to make it so I have three of the nav links on the left and then I want my full name, with photography under it in smaller. But I want the whole thing, my name and photography to act as one link that would take them to the whole page and then the other three nav links on the right of that.

The problem I'm running into, and I know this is probably stupid, is whenever I try to put photography under my name it also brings down the last three nav links and I also can't get it all to stay centered across the page.

```
    <head>
        <title>my name|Photography</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

           <header>

               <nav>

                   <ul>

                       <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>

                   </ul>

                   <h1>My Full Name</h1>

                   <h3>Photography</h3>

                   <ul>

                       <li><a href="#">instagram</a></li>

                       <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>

                       <li><a href="#">book</a></li>

                   </ul>

               </nav>

           </header> 

    </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
html{
background: url(images/7518828608_IMG_4655.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed;
size:cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
}
header{
background:;
color: white;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
}

header h1{
    margin:0;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    font-family: cursive;
}

header h3{
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px 10px 5px 5px;
    font-family: cursive;
}

nav ul{
    margin:0;
    display:inline;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-family: inherit
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For bringing the whole header contents to the center: add text-align in header e.g. {text-align: center;}

Comment: that was such a simple fix to my problem. I really appreciate it. now all I have to do is figure out how to get photography to be under full name and make it one link

Answer (score 0):

If you know how much width you require for your `full name` and `my photography` to fit , then i would wrap both h1 and h2 in an  tag and style it like so:

```
<a href="#test" style="max-width: 150px; display: inline-
block;">
    <h1>My Full Name</h1>
    <h3>Photography</h3>
</a>
```

and style h1 and h3 to display: block;

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest making it a bit more dynamic and simplify by removing redundant components. Nav can just list out links as part of the element like:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">home</a>
        <a href="#">about</a>
        <a href="#">portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">
            <h1>My Full Name</h1>
            <h3>Photography</h3>
        </a>
        <a href="#">instagram</a>
        <a href="#">contact</a>
        <a href="#">book</a>            
    </nav>
</header>
```

This includes your name and photography stacked and within one link. CSS can use flex and align its contents and should make it more dynamic depending on screen resolution.

```
html {
    background: url(images/7518828608_IMG_4655.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed;
    size:cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
}

header {
    color: white;
    font-family: cursive;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    display: inline-block;
}

h1, h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

nav a:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to solve the problem...I've attached the code snippet...

```css
html {
    background: url(images/7518828608_IMG_4655.JPG) no-repeat center center fixed;
    size:cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
}

header {
    color: white;
    font-family: cursive;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
    display: inline-block;
}

h1, h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

nav a:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#">
            <h2>My Full Name</h2>
            <h3>Photography</h3>
        </a>
        <a href="#">Instagram</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">Book</a>            
    </nav>
</header>
```